# Matching Outside of a C-style String/Comment

Tags: python, regex

Using regular expressions is it possible to require that a match not be inside of:

- A C-style double quoted string (where `\` is the escape character);
- a single line `//` comment;
- a multi-line `/*` to `*/` comment.

So if I am searching for `foo` I would expect

```
bar("// foo\"", foo, /* foo // */ 2, 3); // foo
```

to match only the second instance.  Individually, matching the positive conditions in isolation is not an issue :

- Double quoted string: `"((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"`;
- for single line comments: `//(?:.*?)`;
- for multi-line comments: `/\*(?:.*?)\*/`.

However am unsure how to combine all of these consistently (and then how to subsequently negate the condition).  A `//` is a single line comment if it is not inside of a double quoted string.  Similarly with a multi-line comment.

I am using Python's `re` module for matching.

Comment: Show what you have tried, then we can help you improve your regex. You want to learn from it eventually don't you?

Comment: And what have you tried so far? At least the single-line comment should be *very* easy.

Comment: Updated; the positive conditions are no issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually trying to achieve?  It is certainly possible to do this with a regex, but it looks like you are trying to strip comments from C code by returning everything that is *not* a comment.  An easier way might be to use `re.sub` to replace anything matching a comment with an empty string.  Then you can use the regex's you've already developed:

```
mycode = ...
patterns = [r'"((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"', r'//(?:.*?)', r'/\*(?:.*?)\*/']
for pattern in patterns:
    mycode = re.sub(pattern, '', mycode)
```

This code is not tested, and I suspect that your will run into trouble with your regex's when you test them on a multiline document.  Specifically, have a look at the [re.M](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.M) flag and the `^` and `$` expressions.  You also don't need the non-capturing parentheses.

Comment: I am looking to rename variables in some automatically generated C code.  However, I would rather not rename the comments/string literals.  My idea was therefore to only consider matches outside of comments and strings.

Comment: That's actually quite complicated - you also need to consider how to define whether something is a variable.  E.g. `var = 4;` vs `for(var=0;var!=5;var++)` vs `my_var=4;`.  It is doable, because language parsers do it, but it's not straightforward, and you will probably spend just as long building the regex as you would changing it manually.  If your code is relatively short, it will probably be faster to do it manually, or use a refactoring tool.  Your IDE may have one built in.